# Generated client code from wsdl does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am creating client for soap service on .Net Core. Code was generated from wsdl
https://testfinance.post.ee/finance/erp/erpServices.wsdl

Code which should send request

```
var client = new ErpDataExchangeClient(
                ErpDataExchangeClientBase.EndpointConfiguration.ErpDataExchangeSoap11);

var eInvoiceRequest = new EInvoiceRequest()
{
        authPhrase = "10****:rskzsbkqdlmlmaeoyhmzeyttacozypxbbwqudna***********",
                E_Invoice = GetEinvoice()
};

 var result = client.EInvoiceAsync(eInvoiceRequest).Result;
```

`GetEinvoice()` - returns XMl document

On runtime I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Contract requires Duplex, but
>   Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured
>   properly to support it.'

Service should be fine. This is a big company API.

Nothing was changed, used only automatically generated code.
What should I do to be able make API calls for this SOAP service

Comment: [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services) may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, there described point with wsDualHttpBinding, it could be usefull, but service endpoit is HTTPS. wsDualHttpBinding works only with HTTP

Comment: How did you generate the client code? As this [WCF Features in .Net Core 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md), duplex binding is not supported.

Comment: Project is Net Core 2.2. Generated as Connected Services-> Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider -> Uri -> Finish